# When to use new for a global scope

Tags: c++

I looked some code it says one of the reason to use "new" is to make a pointer not being destroyed after a function. For example

```
void input(string name, int age)
{
  student *st = new student(name,age);
  st->change();
}
int main(){
  input("guagua",25);
  if(!st){ cout<<"there is a pointer"<<endl;}
  delete st;
  return 0;
}
```

I have a simple class student whose head file looks like this, where change funtion just cout a sentence.

```
class student{

  public:
    student(string na, int ag);
    void change();
  private:
    string name;
    int age;
};
```

If new allocate a memory then I should be able to see "there is a pointer". However, this program cannot be compiled and the error is

```
    ‘st’ was not declared in this scope
```

How could I make st be visible after input function?

Comment: That's not very good code. Don't know where you got it from, but you should read [a good book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) instead.

Comment: What you have read is correct, but your code declares the pointer in the local scope of the function `input`, hence the error message that it is not visible in the scope of `main`. You could move it out of the `main` function so that it becomes global.

Comment: "global scope" and "heap allocation" are two completely different and unrelated topics. Your question deals with the later.

Comment: Please don't put the answer into the question. Just accept the best one, optionally writing it yourself first.

Answer (score 2):

In this example the object has been created and still exists in memory, but you don't have a pointer to it anymore.

The reason is that `st` goes out of scope in `input` and so the value of the pointer (where the objects is) is lost.

The `st` in the `main` function has not been declared in that scope and so it doesn't exist there.

So in this example you would need to return the pointer with something like:

```
student* input(string name, int age)
{
  student *st = new student(name,age);
  st->change();
  return st;
}
```

then you can use it:

```
int main(){
  auto st = input("guagua",25);
  if(!st){ cout<<"there is a pointer"<<endl;}
  delete st;
  return 0;
}
```

---

Another option could be to use a global variable for `st`, or to use a smart pointer.

`std::shared_ptr` in general could be a drop-in replacement for a raw pointer, but you should prefer the use of a `std::unique_ptr` if you don't need shared ownership.

Here is an example:

```
std::unique_ptr<student> input(string name, int age)
{
    auto st = std::make_unique<student>(name, age);
    st->change();
    return st;
}

int main(){
    auto st = input("guagua", 25);
    if(!st){ cout << "there is a pointer" << endl; }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why would `std::shared_ptr` be best?

Comment: @BenjaminLindley because then there is no need to remember to `delete`. Did I miss something?

Comment: That's a reason to use a smart pointer. But why a shared pointer specifically?

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Because it is practically a drop-in replacement for a raw pointer. I am curious what else you have in mind?

Comment: I don't mind suggesting the use of `std::shared_ptr`. I only take issue with suggesting it is the best option without a demonstration that shared ownership is required. And the alternative is `std::unique_ptr`, which should be the default if no such demonstration has been made.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Fair enough. Best is a strong word.